# Problem with a days select in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've a problem with three selects for birth of date (Day,Month,Year) in IE. This is the HTML.

```
<li><label for="dobYear">Date of birth*:</label>
<select name="dobDay" id="dobDay">
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                     <option value="6">6</option>
                     <option value="7">7</option>
                     <option value="8">8</option>
                     <option value="9">9</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                     <option value="13">13</option>
                     <option value="14">14</option>
                     <option value="15">15</option>
                     <option value="16">16</option>
                     <option value="17">17</option>
                     <option value="18">18</option>
                     <option value="19">19</option>
                     <option value="20">20</option>
                     <option value="21">21</option>
                     <option value="22">22</option>
                     <option value="23">23</option>
                     <option value="24">24</option>
                     <option value="25">25</option>
                     <option value="26">26</option>
                     <option value="27">27</option>
                     <option value="28">28</option>
                     <option value="29">29</option>
                     <option value="30">30</option>
                     <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="dobMonth" id="dobMonth" onchange="getDays();">
                      <option value="01">Jan</option>
                      <option value="02">Fev</option>
                      <option value="03">Mar</option>
                      <option value="04">Apr</option>
                      <option value="05">May</option>
                      <option value="06">Jun</option>
                      <option value="07">Jul</option>
                      <option value="08">Aug</option>
                      <option value="09">Sep</option>
                      <option value="10">Oct</option>
                      <option value="11">Nov</option>
                      <option value="12">Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="dobYear" id="dobYear" onchange="getDays();">
                      <option value="2010">2010</option>
                      <option value="2009">2009</option>
                      <option value="2008">2008</option>
                      <option value="2007">2007</option>
                      <option value="2006">2006</option>
                      <option value="2005">2005</option>
                    </select>
</li>
```

and I have a javascript code to count number of days in every month/year

```
function getDays()
{
var month = document.getElementById("dobMonth").options[document.getElementById("dobMonth").selectedIndex].value;
var year=document.getElementById("dobYear").options[document.getElementById("dobYear").selectedIndex].value;
var daysoutput;
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
        var j = 31;
    }
     else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11){
          var j = 30;
    }
    else{
        if (year%4==0){
               j=29;
        }
else{
j=28;
}
}
for (var i=1;i<=j;i++){
daysoutput+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
document.getElementById('dobDay').innerHTML=daysoutput;
}
```

with FF, this is okay, but in IE instead after selecting a month/year , the days select becomes empty!

and I don't know why? ,but I doubt the problem is with `innerHTML`.

thank you

Comment: February 29th, 2000 does not exist.

Comment: You really should format your code properly...

Comment: I added the "internet-explorer" tag, since it seems to be an ie specific bug. Anyway, I think the problem is in your JS. Try adding `alert(daysoutput);`at the end of your function to see its value . And get some error console for JavaScript

Comment: @Goran I've added it , and it's okey with FF

Comment: @Goran so the problem is not with the dayoutput variable

Comment: @SLaks I didn't know really that ... thank you

Comment: @Goran if you'are interested in the solution, I've solved it. you can see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to add options is using the .add() method of the `options` collection of the drop down element.

Working example:

```js
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var dtNow = new Date();
    var year = dtNow.getFullYear();
    FillDropDownRange("ddlMonth", 1, 12, dtNow.getMonth() + 1);
    FillDropDownRange("ddlYear", year - 5, year, year);
    FillDays();
};
    
function FillDropDownRange(oDDL, rangeStart, rangeEnd, nSelectedValue) {
    if (typeof oDDL == "string")
        oDDL = document.getElementById(oDDL);
    while (oDDL.options.length > 0)
        oDDL.removeChild(oDDL.options[0]);
    for (var i = rangeStart; i <= rangeEnd; i++) {
        var option = new Option();
        option.text = i + "";
        option.value = i + "";
        if (typeof nSelectedValue != "undefined" && i == nSelectedValue)
            option.selected = "selected";
        oDDL.options.add(option);
    }
}

function FillDays() {
    var month = parseInt(document.getElementById("ddlMonth").value);
    var year = parseInt(document.getElementById("ddlYear").value);
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(1);    
    date.setMonth(month - 1);
    date.setFullYear(year);
    var daysCount = 0;
    while (date.getMonth() == (month - 1)) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        daysCount++;
    }
    FillDropDownRange("ddlDay", 1, daysCount);
}
```

```html
<select id="ddlDay"></select> /
<select id="ddlMonth" onchange="FillDays();"></select> / 
<select id="ddlYear" onchange="FillDays();"></select>
```

I also gave "safe" way to get the number of days given specific month and year.

Comment: Tested under Chrome, Firefox and IE8

Comment: @thank you, but I've solved the problem and it's now okey...:-)

Comment: you can see the answer , +1 for your answer

Comment: @Simo I don't think your solution is good practice but I can't force my opinion.. please consider using "my way" - anyhow thanks for accepting it. :-)

Comment: thank you friend :) and be sure that I will use it in the next select (my project is full of selects :P )

Comment: there is a bug month feb doesn't displays no of days

Comment: @sanojlawrence wow talking about edge cases... this was caused due to setting the month before setting the day, so today is the 30th to December, and trying to set the day to 30 on February caused it to skip to March, hence 0 days were found. Fixed now and made into a snippet, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you friends , I've solved the problem and it's now okey with IE:

this is the solution:

I changed this line :

```
<label for="dobYear">Date of birth*:</label><select name="dobDay" id="dobDay"> in the html code to this
```

to this ;

```
<span id="days"><label for="dobYear">Date of birth*:</label>
                     <select name="dobDay" id="dobDay">
```

as you can see , I've added a container (parent) span to select

then I changed the js code as follows:

```
    for (var i=1;i<=j;i++){
daysoutput+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
document.getElementById('dobDay').innerHTML=daysoutput;
```

becomes :

```
for (var i=1;i<=j;i++){
daysoutput+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
}
document.getElementById("days").innerHTML='<label for="dobYear">Date of birth*:</label><select name="dobDay" id="dobDay">'+daysoutput+'</select></label>';
```

it may appear that IE doesn't apply the innerHTML to a select tag, then I've added a span tag that contains this select , and changed its innerHTML with javascript

thank you

Comment: Ha ha.. it doesn't apply it to the `select` but does for `span`. What joke.. Good that it works now

Comment: @Goran, it's really a joke, hihihi

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the innerHTML of a select element with Internet Explorer.

You should be using new Option().

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
sel.options.length = 0; //removes all options
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  var newOpt = new Option("text" + i, "value" + i);
  sel.options[i] = newOpt;
}
```

You could also use createElement instead of new Option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to case your option value to string or parseInt to compare. It might fixed your problem. For instance:

```
if(month == 3)
```

to

```
if(month == "3")
```

or

```
if(parseInt(month) == 3)
```

Comment: This is not an issue in JavaScript: `var m="3"; [m==3,m=="3",m==3.0] //-> [true, true, true]`.

Comment: the problem is not with dayoutput variable, it takes properly the value I want it to take.

Comment: @nofortee, thank you for your reply, but changing the 3 to "3" doesn't change anything, the problem is that IE doesn't apply innerHTML to a select you can see my last answer

Comment: OK!! Glad you to hear your problem's been solved. I think there's a lot of example code on how to do this. I'm little lazy, then I prefer to use other's code...LOL. But if you need, I can sent you a copy...^_^

Comment: @nofortee, thank you ! I will be pleased if you send me some code that can be useful in some next situations.;) here's the mail : simotaqi@gmail.com